# How to write quick toggle list in jquery?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want to add toggle attribute to mysite. When I click hide/show button, it should show/hide divs. According to alphabetical order, a user who click a letter will show the content which starts with that letter. So my code is here :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button_letter_A').click(function() {
        $('#portfolio_item_A').toggle();

    });
     $('#button_letter_B').click(function() {
        $('#portfolio_item_B').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Instead of writing all letters in an order; how to write this code in a quick way. For example; can I make it with for loops in javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// target everything with IDs that start with 'button_letter'
$("[id^='button_letter']").click(function () {

    // split the letter out of the ID
    // of the clicked element and use it to target
    // the correct div
    $("#portfolio_item_" + this.id.split("_")[2]).toggle();
});
```

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

if your naming is consistent just make a toggle function and pass the letter to be toggled.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#button_letter_'+ letter).click(function() {
        custom_accordion(letter);
    });
   }

function custom_accordion(letter){
           $('#portfolio_item_'+letter).toggle();
}

});
</script>
```

call the function on click by passing letter u want to......

This link has explanation on jquery [custom toggle](http://sreevathsabv.blogspot.in/2012/03/using-multiple-accordion-in-jquery-with.html)